# R set all variables to Global Environment

Tags: r

Is there a way to set all variables within a local environment to global Environment? I know how to do this for single variable. What if I have 30+ variables? Can I send all local workspace into global? Thanks.

```
myfunction=function(){
    assign("a", 10, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
myfunction()
print (a)
```

or in case of Rnw file. I can do

```
a=3
environment(a)=.GlobalEnv
```

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo. I was just calling the function at line 3, not redefining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a function, allglobal(), gets the objects (vars and functions) in the environment it was called (parent.frame) and assigns all of them to the global environment. The second function is a test. After it is run, "test1" and "test2" exist in the global environment:

```
allglobal <- function() {
    lss <- ls(envir = parent.frame())
    for (i in lss) {
        assign(i, get(i, envir = parent.frame()), envir = .GlobalEnv)
    }
}

testallglob <- function() {
    test1 <- 1
    test2 <- function() 2
    allglobal()
}
```

Comment: You can use `list2env` and `mget` to make `allglobal` more succinct: `allglobal <- function() list2env(mget(ls(name = parent.frame()), envir = parent.frame()), envir = .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: Will check that, seems to get rid of the loop if OK.

Comment: It worked! Thanks man! @WeihuangWong

Answer (score 1):

A small modification of your method will work:

```
vars <- ls(all = TRUE)
for (i in 1:length(vars)){
assign(vars[i], get(vars[i]), envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

This uses a for loop to programmatically access the name of each variable in the local environment and then assigns each variable to the same name in .GlobalEnv.